# Copy RDS DB snapshots across region incrementally

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to copy RDS DB snapshots across region. Do AWS support incremental copying of the DB snapshot across region by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes AWS supports incremental copying for the DB across region.

Check this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-region-snapshot-copy-for-amazon-rds/

Comment: Thanks for answering. I do have a very naive question. How do AWS knows whether a full snapshot copy is required or an incremental?

Comment: Sorry not familiar with that process